# ListView Hierarchical data - ASP.Net

Tags: controls, asp.net-3.5

I'm working on an asp.net application where I need to display records in the form of a ListBox in hierarchical format (parent-child records). I managed to do that using ASP.Net 3.5 ListView Control, but I couldn't get the functionalities of the ListBox control like selecting multiple items. Can somebody guide me on how to do that using ListView control or is there a better way to display data in a hierarchical manner. We don't like to use any kind of Tree control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer to your question but Telerik has got a TreeView control that supports your requested functionality.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/validating/defaultcs.aspx

The sample that demos the validation functionality comes up with a hierachical list of products and orders related to that product.

You may want to spend some time and see if you can mimic the behaviour of the TreeView control.